# How to combine regular expression and string format to get expected digits code?

Tags: python, regex, string

I'd like to use a combination of regular expression and string format to match some string of the type, for example 'USA10Y1Y'.

```
code = 'USA'
b = 1
r'{}\d{{1,2}}Y{}Y'.format(code, b)
>>> 'USA\\d{1,2}Y1Y'
```

What I need is following, as they are going to put in `re.search`

```
>>> 'USA\d{1,2}Y1Y'
```

How can I get rid of the extra slash before \d?

Comment: Did you try out the resulting pattern? It will work: `re.findall(r'{}\d{{1,2}}Y{}Y'.format(code, b), 'USA10Y1Y')` -> `['USA10Y1Y']`

Comment: `print(r'{}\d{{1,2}}Y{}Y'.format(code, b))` shows the desired string i.e. 'USA\d{1,2}Y1Y.  What you are seeing is the representation from `__repr__`.